# Div Anchor Clickable Even Outside of Div

Tags: html, css, anchor, href, clickable

I have a very simple question. Whenever I surround a div with a pair of anchor tags, the div becomes clickable, but for some reason the clickable part extends past the dimensions of the div itself and goes across the page. How do I make the div clickable within it's boundaries and not stretched across the page? I have included my code here.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>My Webpage</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "mystyles.css" type = "text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "link"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
#link {
background-color: #00ccee;
border: solid black 2px;
border-radius: 25px;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
transition: 1s;
}

#link:hover{
background-color: blue;
width: 160px;
height: 60px;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: `height` and `width` can be issue

Comment: can u post the `mystyle.css` also ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/bVVdaP

all you have to do is put a link inside the div and add this to your css on the `a`

```
a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

This will make sure the link expands fully inside the divs width+height.

If you want the link to be outside of your div my suggesgion would be to make it a fixed width then you can just adjust that to the size of your div(percentages for responsive)

Heres a little info on wrapping a tags around divs

[Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

> Depending on the version of HTML you're catering to:
>
> - **[HTML 4.01][1]** specifies that `<a>` elements may only contain [inline elements][3]. A `<div>` is a [block element][2], so it may not
>     appear inside an `<a>`.
>
>   Of course you are at liberty to style an inline element such that it
>     *appears* to be a block, or indeed style a block so that it is rendered inline. The use of the terms `inline` and `block` in HTML
>     refers to the relationship of the elements to the semantic structure
>     of the document, whereas the same terms in CSS are related more to the
>     visual styling of the elements. If you make inline elements display in
>     a blocky manner, that's fine.
>
>   However you should ensure that the structure of the document still
>     makes sense when CSS is not present, for example when accessed via an
>     assistive technology such as a screen reader - or indeed when examined
>     by the mighty Googlebot.
> - **[HTML 5][4]** states that the `<a>` element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire
>     sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g.
>     buttons or other links)".
>
>   [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A   [2]:
>     http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#block   [3]:
>     http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline   [4]:
>     http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I didn't realize I didn't include the anchor. I've tried to wrap the div itself in the anchor, and that caused some weird behavior. I'm just curious why the anchor should be inside of it instead?